# How to display a modelpopup window using angularJS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I need to show a model popup window in a button click.can any one suggest the best method to achieve this in angularjs without BootstrpJS?

I tried the below and is not working. :(

**html**

```
    <div>
      <button ng-click='toggleModal()'>Add Dataset</button>
        <modal-dialog info='modalShown' show='modalShown' width='400px'     height='60%'>
            <p>Modal Content Goes here</p>

  </modal-dialog>
    </div>
```

**controller**

```
app.controller('DataController', function ($scope,$http) {

    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function () {
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };


 $http.get("/api/product").then(function (responses) {
        $scope.ProductData = responses.data;
               });
.......
........
});

app.directive('modalDialog', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            show: '=info'
        },
        replace: true, // Replace with the template below
        transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.dialogStyle = {};
            if (attrs.width)
                scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
            if (attrs.height)
                scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
            scope.hideModal = function () {
                scope.show = false;
            };
        },
        template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>X</div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"
    };
});
```

Comment: you need to style the "modal" with html/css in your page. and on button click you can make it appear (or you can use `jQuery.fadeIn()` or something). Not many ppl will give you a complete answer here, you have to try yourself first and show what problems you're facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're messing with your scope a little too much. If you check out http://codepen.io/dboots/pen/vLeXPj, I used the same `$scope.showModal` variable and the same the same `$scope.toggleModal` function to show/hide.

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .controller('DataController', function($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function() {
      $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
  })
  .directive('modalDialog', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true, // Replace with the template below
      transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.dialogStyle = {};
        if (attrs.width)
          scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
        if (attrs.height)
          scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
      },
      template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='showModal'><div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='toggleModal()'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='toggleModal()'>X</div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"

    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a directive. Then include it in your controller.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I guess a vague question deserves a vague answer.

Comment: @hunter-turner Wanted the best method. No attempt to show (s)he tried to solve it.

Comment: Oh I'm not insulting you! I agree with you completely, just making an observation. :)

Comment: Didn't take it that way!